# Глаза, следящие за курсором на JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Хотел сделать глаза, следящие за курсором, однако они либо отстают от него, либо спешат, что не так ?
За основу взял этот гайд : https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-an-eye-tracking-alien-with-javascript-solution-to-code-challenge-4

```js
let ufo = document.querySelector('body');
ufo.addEventListener('mousemove', (m) => {
  let eyes = document.querySelector('.f-eye');
  let mouseX = (eyes.getBoundingClientRect().left);
  let mouseY = (eyes.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  let radianDegrees = Math.atan2(m.pageX - mouseX, m.pageY - mouseY);
  let rotationDegrees = (radianDegrees * (180/ Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
  eyes.style.transform = `rotate(${rotationDegrees}deg)`;
});
ufo.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let eyes = document.querySelector('.s-eye ');
  let mouseX = (eyes.getBoundingClientRect().left); 
  let mouseY = (eyes.getBoundingClientRect().top);
  let radianDegrees = Math.atan2(e.pageX - mouseX, e.pageY - mouseY);
  let rotationDegrees = (radianDegrees * (180/ Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
  eyes.style.transform = `rotate(${rotationDegrees}deg)`;
});
```

```css
.eyes{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-top: 500px;
    border:5px solid red;
   
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;

}
.f-eye{
    position: absolute;
    border:5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;



}
.s-eye{
    position: relative;
    border:5px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 125px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;



}
.pupil{
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.background{
    height: 1920px;
    width: 1080px;
    background-color: #b6c9f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/eyes.css">
    

</head>
<body>
    <div class="background" id="background">
        <div class="eyes" id="eyes">
            <div class="f-eye">
                <div class="pupil">
                </div>
        
            </div>
            <div class="s-eye">
                <div class="pupil">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
    <script src="./js/eyesSup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) просто рекомендация - зачем вы переводите радианы в градусы, когда можно поворот указывать в радианах?

```
let radianDegrees = Math.atan2(m.pageX - mouseX, - m.pageY + mouseY);
eyes.style.transform = `rotate(${radianDegrees }rad)`;
```

2) попробуйте установить 0 градусов - разве глаза у вас смотрят вверх? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.pupil{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: 0;
}
```

сделайте так (2 последние строчки), чтобы глаза смотрели строго вверх (и `margin` тоже в 0 надо убрать)

3) ну и с формулой как-то не очень - ведь надо относительно центра глаза считать

```
ufo.addEventListener('mousemove', (m) => {
  const eyes = document.querySelector('.f-eye');
  const rect = eyes.getBoundingClientRect();
  const eyeX = (rect.left + rect.right) / 2;
  const eyeY = (rect.top + rect.bottom) / 2;
    
  let radianDegrees = - Math.atan2(eyeX - m.pageX, eyeY - m.pageY);
  eyes.style.transform = `rotate(${radianDegrees}rad)`;
});
```

вот в таком виде глаза работают (к примеру мышка между глазами)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]