# Как реализовать круг с градусами на JS?

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать что то похожее как на этом сайте
https://cssgradient.io/gradient-backgrounds/
Вот такой круг градусов который меняется от положения курсора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

была тема "глаза, следящие за курсором"

[Глаза, следящие за курсором на JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182609/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js/1182620#1182620)

по сути вам надо сделать тоже самое, только вместо того, чтобы менять позицию глаз выводить значение угла (который там также вычисляется)

т.е. алгоритм должен быть таким:

1. определяете центр круга (определяете его границы и вычисляете центр)
2. определяете положение курсора мыши в окне
3. вычисляете угол (лучше использовать `asin`, `acos`, а не `atan`, чтобы не получить деление на 0 на некоторых углах)
4. выводите положение стрелочки на круге (используя стиль трансформации поворота на нужный угол)
5. выводите значение угла

Comment: большое спасибо